# VB .NET CONNECT TO LOCAL .MDB

Tags: database, vb.net, authentication, passwords, local

Hi guys can u tell me how can I connect to the protected by login and password local computer and open a .mdb file which one is on this computer?

Below is a code where Z is a local computer but B is a folder where we have our database. But all time i got error with that i dont have premission to open magazyn.mdb. Can u tell me what i must add to this connectionString to open this .mdb file

```
 conn.ConnectionString = _
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=" & _
"\\z\b\magazyn.mdb;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
conn.ConnectionString = _
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
"\\z\b\magazyn.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=password;"
```

See [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access) for further examples.

Comment: yes I use this one but i got error somthing like this  " Cant open application, information file about group no exist or it was open in exclusiveness mode  by other user"

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing database file on shared folder. You must set share `\\z\b` properties (and file system security too) to allow read/write access and additionally allow file creation - access needs to create lock (*.ldf) file.

Comment: SOLVED ! .MDW file was needed