# Using a variable in connection string for a portion of Database name so it doesnt have to be hard coded for every user

Tags: database, vb.net, database-connection, connection-string, oledb

My program uses a Database  that is named (County Hunter - K8EMS.mdb) on my computer. What I want to do is use a variable that a user can enter on their screen and pick the DB to search on their computer                             ( County Hunter - "Variable".mdb). As every user has a different call where the variable will go.

This Database is created by another program used by the county hunter, all I want to do is search a table in this DB to see if a field is NULL or used. I have an input text box on the screen so they can enter their call and would like to use that input to finish naming the database to search, so hard coding and compiling wouldn't need to be done for every user.

I am using Visual Basic, in Microsoft visual studio 17.

```
     Dim conn As OleDbConnection
     Dim ds As New DataSet
     Dim dt As New DataTable
     ds.Tables.Add(dt)
     Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
     Dim connString = "(Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Logger Data\County Hunter -  " ' & mcall.text &'""' &.mdb&'"Jet OLEDB:Database.[County Hunter- (mcall,text.mdb) Password = ########;)"
```

The MDB is old Access database as the program that installed the database is in VB6. The connection string shows errors but I am fairly new to Access and I 
need some direction on how to make this work.

[image: variable input screen]

Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It looks you are not exactly new here but it is your first question. As you know what you want to do, what exactly is preventing you from doing it? Have you looked into the Help Center on how to ask a good question here in SO? What programming language are you using? Tag the question with the language name and share the relevant bit of code where you have trouble. It is not even apparent if you are programming yourself or just using some other's program. Asking a good question prevents you from being doownvoted and helps others to help you too.

Comment: I edited the question I hope it is more clear now

Comment: It is *much* better now. It looks you have trouble interpolating your connection string with variables. It is just a matter of joining `"..." & varname & "..."` parts but you seem to have other malformed parts in the string.

Comment: Something like `Dim connString = "(Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Logger Data\County Hunter -  " & mcall.text & ".mdb; Password = ########;)"` makes more sense to me but I my VB is very rusty. Wait for the help of others. I tagged your post for a larger relevant audience.

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27876895/connecting-to-an-mdb-file-using-odbcconnection-in-vs2013) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453138/vb-net-connect-to-local-mdb)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this every time, but that would be a hassle.  You can’t put it in the DB, because that is what you are locating...I would suggest putting it in the config file.

```
Dim  config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)

Dim appSettings = CType(config.GetSection("appSettings"), AppSettingsSection)
Dim insensitive = StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase

If (Not appSettings.AllKeys.Any(Function(key)
        string.Compare(key, "name", insensitive) = 0)) Then
    appSettings.Settings.Add("name", "bar")

    config.Save()
End If
```